Customizing section headings in KOMAscript: dot after section title
I am using the scrartcl class and want to customize the \subsection command. In particular, I want to add a dot behind the subsection title, i.e. something like this:

1.2. The Subsection Title.

but obviously, I want to have this automated, and not do the dot myself (so I don't want to write \subsection{The Subsection Title.} but only \subsection{The Subsection Title} -- i.e. no manual dot).
Quick (and Dirty?) Approach:
I suppose I could just do something along the lines of \newcommand{\mysubsection}[1]{\subsection{#1.}}, but wonder whether there is a KOMAscript-native way to do this (given the aim of the KOMA classes being simpler customizability).
Any insights much appreciated, whether I am asking for too much and this is simply not intended, or whether there actually is the one and only right way of doing this.

Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

As I was explicitly asking for a KOMA native way of doing this, in my opinion a MWE would only have distracted from my actual question. Telling from your answer I take that there is no intended way (as in special KOMA command) for this (in contrast to \RedeclareSectionCommand), but it requires a workaround either redefining \sectionlinesformat or \subsection. Though your way of doing this is much nicer than mine.

A MWE is always useful. See the previous link and the link there for reasons.

Unfortunately you've not shown a minimal working example, so I, e.g., don't know, whether or not you already reconfigure the subsection headings.
KOMA-Script provides command \sectionlinesformat, which is used to format the free standing headings of sectioning style section. By default this style is used for \section, \subsection, and \subsubsection.
The first argument is the level name, e.g., section, subsection …
The second argument is the indent value.
The third argument is the number inclusive formatting (font change etc.).
The fourth argument is the text inclusive formatting (font change etc.).
As shown in the KOMA-Script documentations, the default definition is:
\newcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}%
}

Replacing {#4} by {#4.} would be enough to add the dot at the end of all sectioning levels handled by \sectionlinesformat. But you want to limit it to subsections, so something like
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4\Ifstr{#1}{subsection}{.}{}}%
}

would do it.
It additionally seems, that you want to add a . also after the number. This can be done for all sectioning levels (and all numbers, that may depend on sectioning numbers) using option numbers=withenddot. Alternatively you can redefine \subsectionformat to change it only for subsections:
\renewcommand{\subsectionformat}{\thesubsection.\enskip}

In the following example I use the numbers=withenddot method to get a more consistent result:
\documentclass[numbers=withenddot]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4\Ifstr{#1}{subsection}{.}{}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}


See the KOMA-Script documentation (available in English and German) for more information about the used options and commands.
Another suggestion that would be independent from using a KOMA-Script class, would be to copy the definition of \subsection to a new command, e.g., \SubSection and redefine \subsection adding the dot to the mandatory argument of the copied command:
\documentclass[numbers=withenddot]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass{article}% would also work

\usepackage{mwe}

\NewCommandCopy{\SubSection}{\subsection}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection} {sO{#2}m}
  {%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\SubSection*{#3.}}{\SubSection[#2]{#3.}}%
  }

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}

The result is the same as shown above, but it would also work, if you use, e.g., article instead of scrartcl.

BTW: If you are using a very old LaTeX installation you may get an error, because of an undefined \Ifstr. In this case → https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/Warning_Deprecated_if/

Nice, thanks a lot for the very in depth answer! (I'll comment below the original message regarding the minimal working example)
